# How can I get right-size this column to show entire filename?

Tags: macos, finder

How can I get right-size this column to show the entire filename in the Finder on Mavericks? 
It used to work in previous OSs. I am in column view. Right-size all columns doesn't work either. It keeps leaving ... where the filename should be.

[image: Listing of filenames with ... instead of complete name]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An even better solution I found is XtraFinder. It sets my Finder windows *permanently* to right-size every column, so I can always see the entire filename. It saves me an amazing amount of time. I found it here: http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/42067/xtrafinder

Answer (score 3):

Just double clic on the separator between the columns ;)

Comment: That works, except not in the Time Machine backups.backupdb folder. A double-click does nothing there for me. It only worked once. But I can't repeat it.